# Error when trying to import a standalone component in a module

Tags: angular, angular15, angular-standalone-components

I recently upgraded my project from Angular 13 to Angular 15. And now I'm trying to make some of the existing components independent.

I'm trying to use a standalone component in a regular NgModule but I get this error:

Class ExchangeCategoriesAutocompleteComponent is not an Angular module.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with Angular, this problem occurred because my webstorm version was old. after upgrading to 2022.3.2 problem solved